# How should I convert this object from .PSD to HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, psd

[image: The object]

Should I make this object from pure CSS if it is possible or us it as a background image for a div?

It goes outside of main content area so I am not sure how to implement it. I guess I should use absolute positioning for the div?

Comment: I believe it is better to use background image.

Comment: This is easy to do using CSS only.

Comment: @connexo Your expertise might say. Would you wanna answer it, as I am interested in that too. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Done.

Comment: Background images are almost never a better option for basic visuals, because you lose out on the text in the image being indexable by search engines, or accessible to screen readers

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CSS only** solution using `border`:

```css
.block {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #909090;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.block h2 {
  background-color: #a9c4c6;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  left: -29px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 29px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.block h2:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 4px 5px;
  border-color: #84a0a2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="block">
  <h2>Furniture</h2>
  <p>Should I make this object from pure CSS if it is possible or us it as a background image for a div?</p>

  <p>It goes outside of main content area so I am not sure how to implement it. I guess I should use absolute positioning for the div?</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to work with css border and we get the same....

FOR more you have to read like this articles how can you work with css shapes https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/.

```css
.main{
padding:20px;
}
.test {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding:10px
  
  
}
h2
{
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 6px 20px 6px 70px;
 color: #555;
 background-color: #AECACC;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #bbb;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #888;
  left:-20px;
}

h2:after
{
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
  /*EDIT border WIDTH as you want fold tringle with css */
 border-bottom: 10px solid #8BA8AA; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: 0px;
  /*EDIT TOP as border width */
 top: -10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="test">
<h2>HEADING HERE</h2>
</div>

</div>
```